# Spring boot @Value annotation returning null

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, annotations, spring-retry

I have a java class, shown below, that is creating a rest template with connection and read timeouts and also creates a retry template that is executing retries whenever a connection and read timeout occurs. I am reading in the values from an application.properties file but for some reason I am getting null values for the values being read in. I have no idea what I can do to fix this. Any advice on this would be appreciated.

```
public class Retry {

@Value("${read.Timeout.InMilliSeconds:-1}")
private Integer readTimeoutInMilliSeconds;

@Value("${connect.Timeout.InMilliSeconds:-1}")
private Integer connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds;

@Value("${backOff.Period.InMilliSeconds:-1}")
private Integer backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds;

@Value("${max.Attempts:-1}")
private Integer maxAttempts;

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(getClientHttpRequestFactory());
    return restTemplate;
}

private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory() {

    HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
    requestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds);
    return requestFactory;
}

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {

    Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExpressions = new HashMap<>();

    // connection and read timeouts
    retryableExpressions.put(ResourceAccessException.class, true);

    // 404
    retryableExpressions.put(RestClientException.class, false);

    SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxAttempts, retryableExpressions);

    FixedBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds);

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(simpleRetryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);

    return retryTemplate;
}

@Bean
public RetryRestTemplate retryRestTemplate() {
    return new RetryRestTemplate(
            restTemplate(),
            retryTemplate());
   }
}
```

application.properties

```
read.Timeout.InMilliSeconds=10000
connect.Timeout.InMilliSeconds=10000
backOff.PeriodInMilliSeconds=10000
max.Attempts=5
```

stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.beans.Retry.getClientHttpRequestFactory(Retry.java:43)
at com.beans.Retry.restTemplate(Retry.java:36)
at com.beans.Services.retryRestTemplate(Services.java:82)
at com.beans.Services$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e8a9c.CGLIB$retryRestTemplate$3(<generated>)
at com.beans.Services$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e8a9c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$65931da6.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
at com.beans.Services$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$819e8a9c.retryRestTemplate(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
... 213 common frames omitted
```

Process finished with exit code 1

RetryRestTemplate

```
public class RetryRestTemplate {

private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private RetryTemplate retryTemplate;

public RetryRestTemplate(RestTemplate restTemplate, RetryTemplate retryTemplate) {
    this.restTemplate = this.restTemplate;
    this.retryTemplate = this.retryTemplate;
}

public ResponseEntity getForEntity(URI uri, Class c) {
    return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
        System.out.println("Check");
        return restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, c);
    });
}

public ResponseEntity exchange(String url, HttpMethod get, HttpEntity headers, Class c) {
    return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
        return restTemplate.exchange(url, get, headers, c);
    });
}

public <T extends Object> ResponseEntity<T> postForEntity(String apiUrl, HttpEntity<Object> entityRequest, Class<T> responseClass) {
    return retryTemplate.execute(retryContext -> {
        return restTemplate.postForEntity(apiUrl, entityRequest, responseClass);
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please add stacktrace ?

Comment: I’m sorry, I’m a little new to java. How do I do that in IntelliJ?

Comment: can you show `application.properties` ?

Comment: Is `Retry` a spring managed class? Try adding `@Component` above `public class Retry`.

Comment: I don’t believe so. I just named it that since in the class I am creating a rest template and retry template to execute retries for my timeouts. I have added the @Component annotation, but unfortunately that did not solve my issue.

Comment: @DaveMichaels just copy full error message with `null` from IntelliJ console and put here

Comment: you need to provide more information like, `package structure` and main class ?

Comment: @DaveMichaels are you using`@Value` imported from `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value` ?

Comment: Yes I am, I have looked at all the import classes I am using.

Comment: I found small mistake - `application.properties` has property `backOff.PeriodInMilliSeconds=10000`, but `@Value` has `backOff.Period.InMilliSeconds`, add the dot

Comment: thank you @tsarenkotxt, but that does not fix the issue.

Comment: looks like a problem in `RetryRestTemplate `, is it your custom class?

Comment: Yes it is, in that class I am specifying where the retry template executes

Comment: could you add  `RetryRestTemplate`  here ?

Comment: added retryresttemplate

Answer (score 1):

Class `Retry` maybe is not managed by Spring. Adding @Configuration upon `Retry` class.

```
@Configuration
public class Retry {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to move `@Value(...)` into corresponging methods as input parameters as follows:

```
private HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getClientHttpRequestFactory(
    @Value("${read.Timeout.InMilliSeconds:-1}") Integer readTimeoutInMilliSeconds,
    @Value("${connect.Timeout.InMilliSeconds:-1}") Integer connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds) {
    ...
}

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate(
    @Value("${backOff.Period.InMilliSeconds:-1}") Integer backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds,
    @Value("${max.Attempts:-1}") Integer maxAttempts) {
    ...
}
```

Or you can also try to create a constructor for `Retry` and use `@Value` for constructor arguments:

```
private Integer readTimeoutInMilliSeconds;
private Integer connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds;
private Integer backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds;
private Integer maxAttempts;

Retry(@Value("${read.Timeout.InMilliSeconds:-1}") Integer readTimeoutInMilliSeconds,
      @Value("${connect.Timeout.InMilliSeconds:-1}") Integer connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds,
      @Value("${backOff.Period.InMilliSeconds:-1}") Integer backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds,
      @Value("${max.Attempts:-1}") Integer maxAttempts) {
    this.readTimeoutInMilliSeconds = readTimeoutInMilliSeconds;
    this.connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds = connectTimeoutInMilliSeconds;
    this.backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds = backOffPeriodInMilliSeconds;
    this.maxAttempts = maxAttempts;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `@Value` annotation, there is other way to get properties value. By using the `Environment` Interface's instance.

Follow the below steps:

1. Add `@Component` annotation on `Retry.java`
2. Import and Autowired `Environment` in your `Retry.java`

   ```
   import org.springframework.core.env.Environment
   @Autowired
   private Environment env;
   ```
3. Get value of the property from env. For example,

   `env.getProperty("read.Timeout.InMilliSeconds","-1");`

There are several other flavors also to the value of the property. You can check it out on [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 0):

2 Things:
1) As others said add configuration
2)Check if you're using Retry as Autowired in any class for which object is created. If any bean class is used in an instantiated object, it returns null.